# How to reference button in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In the HTML, I have a button defined like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleEdit();">Edit</button>
```

At the end of the page, I have this script I am working on:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  function toggleEdit() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var li = btn.parent();
    var textArea = li.children('.readOnly');
    ...
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

I cannot reference the button I have clicked in the script. The `btn` variable is an object, but I don't know anything else than that.

I found many examples on the internet that are using this approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#buttonID').click(function () {
   ...
```

but I cannot reference the button via `ID` because it is added dynamically. So, how do I reference it? Thanks.

Comment: Why not attach the handler to the button at the point where it is added dynamically? At that point, you must have a reference to the button (or at least to its container) so it's not necessary to rediscover it in the DOM.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[type=button]').click(function() {
    ...
});

Assuming you have only one button on your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to keep it your way, you have to tell the code that `this` will refer to the button instead of the actual function.

To do this you can just add an extra argument to the `toggleEdit` function.

The new HTML would look like this (*no apply or call function needed*):

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleEdit(this);">Edit</button>
```

Then your new JavaScript would look like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  <!--
  function toggleEdit(t) {
    var btn = $(t);
    var li = btn.parent();
    var textArea = li.children('.readOnly');
    ...
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the event into the function, and then use that.

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleEdit( event );">Edit</button>
```

Then in your function, you can get the `target` of the event:

```
function toggleEdit( e ) {
    var btn = $( e.target );
    var li = btn.parent();
    var textArea = li.children('.readOnly');
    ...
}
```